# Microsoft Graph. Tracking of page number

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm implementing a method to get groups from AzureAD with paging and filtering for the `displayName` property of the groups. Let's center in the paging. I'm actually able to do page results with the `$top`. But my requirement says that I need to return the data set from a specific page. I'm also able to do that but with not a very elegant solution, making requests to the `NextPageRequest` object of the results to retrieve the specified page. Here's the code:

```
public async Task<List<Group>> GetGroups(string filterText, int page, int pageSize = 1)
{
  var graphClient = _graphSdkHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
  List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

  //Microsoft Graph api allows a minimum page size of 1 and maximum of 999
  if (pageSize < 1 || pageSize > 999)
  {
    return groups;
  }

  try
  {
    IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage graphGroups;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
    {
       graphGroups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{filterText}')").Top(pageSize).GetAsync();
    }
    else
    {
      //if filter text is empty, return all groups
      graphGroups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().OrderBy("displayName").Top(pageSize).GetAsync();
    }

    //navigate to the requested page. This is extremly inefficient as we make requests until we find the right page.
    //$Skip query parameter doesn't work in groups services
    var currentPage = 1;
    while (currentPage < page && graphGroups.NextPageRequest != null && (graphGroups = await graphGroups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0)
    {
      currentPage = currentPage + 1;
    }

    foreach (var graphGroup in graphGroups)
    {
      Group group = _graphSdkHelper.TranslateGroup(graphGroup);
      groups.Add(group);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    _logger.LogError(exception, "Error while searching for groups");
  }

  return groups;
}
```

Question 1: how can I improve and keep track of which page am I? Is this possible? Now I can just request the next page so if I need to access page 20 for example, means 20 requests to azure.

Regarding this post from the AzureAD Graph Api, this is not possible:
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/199bbf92-642a-4bcc-add4-f8023a7684e2/paging-in-azure-ad-graph-client?forum=WindowsAzureAD

I just refuse to think that it's not possible to do real pagination in AzureAD.

Question 2: How can I get the total amount of groups with just one request. It seems that the `$Count`query parameter is not implemented for groups or users:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/query_parameters.md#count-parameter

Thanks

Comment: I'm also searching for an answer how to get the maximum page size, but for Drive items.